# Checking string for non-latin symbols in C++

Tags: c++

For a given path string (`char *`) I'm trying to check
whether it contains some non-Latin symbols.

I'm checking whether it contains at least one character with an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code greater than 127. Is it enough to check by such a way or is there a more effective way?

Comment: ... And what are you going to do, exactly, if you find out that the string "has non-latin symbols in it"?

Comment: Define "non-latin symbol". What character encoding? (UTF-8? ISO-8859-1?) Is é a non-latin symbol? (It probably encodes to >128!) Finally, **there are no ASCII codes >= 128**. If you're checking for ASCII characters with codes >= 128, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I have string ( defined as char* -- legacy code) , that can get values as Japaneze , Korean etc - thus i would like recognize such cases

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what encoding the string is, or whether "é" counts as a "special" character. Why are you making this distinction between Japanese and Latin characters? Very rarely does this need to be done -- more commonly, people try to detect things like this because either there system is ASCII only, or they are having larger issues with character encoding.

Comment: Strings i need to check are file paths.  which are passed to other methods ( which are not to be changed ) . Strings can contain Japaneze , Korean symbols . For such cases I need to do some special processing .

Comment: @lm: If you get a (Windows) path as `char*`, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 3):

To check if there are non-latin characters it is enough to look if character above 128 are present. But remember the meaning of those 'upper bound' characters is not detectable.
Code pages where introduced for all different languages. For russian(cyrillic) you have for example CP1251 (among others). In that codepage the character 8Dh (141d) is Ќ. But in codepage 1256 (Arabic) this means چ. **It has the same value but the meaning is different!**

Unicode 'solves' this problem because all characters have a unique value! (therefore the size is not exact 8 bits, but can also be 16/32bits.

The first 128 characters of Unicode and ASCII match for legacy reasons.

Read this ['The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)'](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Wrong, unfortunately: Shift-JIS defines `¥` as 0x5E < 128, yet `¥` is definitely non-latin/non-ASCII. Since 0x5E is the ASCII code for `\`, and the question is about file paths, this can be a major problem on Windows systems. 7 bits JIS X 0201 is even worse: it _only_ uses codepoints < 128 !

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're doing with the string (i.e. which API function you're using), your operating system and possibly file system, even the driver for the file system device.  You should provide more information.  ASCII characters in the range 32..126 tend to be pretty widely accepted and recognisable (32 being a space, and 127 often looking like one so best avoided): but more may be legal in your particular environment.

Comment: Please see my reply to  thanatos above